# Why "memory in use" = 1g in Spark Standalone?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-standalone

I'm running Apache Spark with Standalone, and when I connect to myip:8080, I always see something like "Memory in use: 120.0 GB Total, 1.0 GB Used". Why only 1Gb is used if much more memory is available? Is it possible (or desirable) to increase the amount of memory that is actually used?

Comment: `spark.executor.memory`?

Comment: It works, thanks. I thought it could only be used for Yarn, but it works on Standalone too.